# New to hadoop space, need to know about following topics

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

1. If Hadoop cannot be used, what are some other alternatives that may be use for parallel processing of data?
2. Numbers vary, but about how many rows (or GB) of data are too few to be worthwhile to build an entire Hadoop application?
3. Can a single Data Node have more than one Map (for the data)?
4. Can a Reduce task send output to another Reduce task?
5. What are the three-possible arrangement of data and task on a HDFS during MR?